# Creating a Marketing List in CRM Dynamics 2013

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm new to both Microsoft CRM and C# development, but I've been tasked with creating a process that creates a marketing list and then adds members (contacts) to that list.

So far the only example I've found for creating a marketing list is here: http://mubashersharif.blogspot.com/2013/06/create-dynamic-marketing-list-in-crm.html

However, when I try this:

```
List dynamicList = new List()
{
    Type = true, //True for Dynamic List
    ListName = "Dynamic List", //Name of the List
    CreatedFromCode = 2, //1 For Account; 2 For Contact; 3 For Lead
    Query = fetchXml
};
Guid _dynamicListId = service.Create(dynamicList);
```

I get the error `Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments.`

I assume this is because it's expecting a `List<T>` and not a CRM List entity. I'm not sure how to specify List and not `List<T>`. Can anyone offer some insight?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jordi's answer is a good one. I ended up using this:

```
Guid _MarketingList
Entity _List = new Entity("list");
OptionSetValue _Createdfromcode = new OptionSetValue(2);

_List["listname"] = "Test Marketing List";
_List["createdfromcode"] = _Createdfromcode;
_List["type"] = false;

_MarketingList = service.Create(_List);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, keep in in mind you first approach was using early bound types and this one uses dynamic entities. I prefer early bound types cause you could spot changes in the schema earlier than with dynamic entities (i.e: someone removing a field, or optionsetvalue, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk using and remove System.Collections.Generic using, or use an alias to distinguish them:

```
using crm = Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
```

Then,

```
crm.List dynamicList = new crm.List()
{
   Type = true, //True for Dynamic List
   ListName = "Dynamic List", //Name of the List
   CreatedFromCode = 2, //1 For Account; 2 For Contact; 3 For Lead
   Query = fetchXml
};
```